# About the use of Schur's complement. Why they are equivalent?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

$$y^{\top}Qy+y^{\top}q+r\geq -ay^{\top}x-b, \qquad \forall y \in \mathbb R^{n}$$

where $Q \succeq 0$. One can use Schur's complement to replace it by an equivalent linear matrix inequality (LMI).

$$\pmatrix{Q&q/2+ax/2\\ q^{\top}/2+ax^{\top}/2& r+b\geq 0} \succeq 0$$

Comment: use \pmatrix{ .. & .. \\ .. & ...} to type matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Schur complement involved. The idea is to use the vector $\pmatrix{y\\1}$ instead of $y$. Then it is easy to check that your first inequality is equivalent to
$$
\pmatrix{y\\1}^T\pmatrix{Q & \frac12(q+ax)\\ \frac12(q+ax)& r+b} \pmatrix{y\\1}\ge0 \quad \forall y.
$$
By scaling, we can replace the vector $\pmatrix{y\\1}$ by any vector $\pmatrix{y\\z}$ with $z\ne0$.

To prove semi-definiteness of the full matrix, we need to check this only for vectors of the form $\pmatrix{y\\0}$. By the considerations above, we have
$$
\pmatrix{y\\\frac1k}^T\pmatrix{Q & \frac12(q+ax)\\ \frac12(q+ax)& r+b} \pmatrix{y\\ \frac1k}\ge0 \quad \forall y, k\in \mathbb N.
$$
Letting $k\to\infty$, gives
$$
\pmatrix{y\\0}^T\pmatrix{Q & \frac12(q+ax)\\ \frac12(q+ax)& r+b} \pmatrix{y\\ 0}\ge0 \quad \forall y,
$$
and the matrix in question is positive semi-definite.

Comment: When taking in (y, z), we have $y^{\top}Qy+zy^{\top}q+z^{2}r\geq -zay^{\top}x-z^{2}b\geq 0$. I do not think it is true for any $z\ne 0$ given the first inequality. I add the constraint that Q is PSD. So, your second part is OK.

Comment: Just divide that inequality by $z^2$, and you obtain the first inequality (for $y/z$). What I prove: if the first inequality is satisfied for all vectors of type $(y,1)$, then it is satisfied for all vectors of type $(y,z)$ with $z\ne0$. The last step is to get rid of the condition $z=0$.

Comment: Thx, I figure it out. But the author of a paper says this equivalence can be obtained from Schur's complement. If this is totally irrelevent to Schur's complement, maybe I should change the question title for other readers to look up.